# Function Not Running When Called

Tags: javascript

I have run into what I think is a rather simple problem, but cannot see the error. I have two functions that I am trying to call (one to display the date and another get focus on a text input box). When I run the web page nothing happens, so I am stumped.

I have created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dk9D9/

And this is the specific javascript that I am working with.

```
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

function todayTxt() {
   var today = new Date();
   return today.getMonth() + 1 + "-" + today.getDate() + "-" + today.getFullYear();
}

var initForm = function ()
{
    document.getElementById('qty1').focus()
}

window.onload = function () {
    $(initForm);
    $(todayTxt);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are passing a function reference to document.getElementById rather than a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like JSFiddle was calling `onload` on the JS input section so setting another `onload` function was preventing the code from running so I disabled it and made the necessary changes to make the page function.

http://jsfiddle.net/keWD5/

(You will need the `window.onload` call in your actual page.)

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `initForm` function as a variable. You should call it with:

```
initForm();
```

The same thing about `todayTxt`:

```
todayTxt();
```

`$` function returns an element by given ID string as a parameter. The valid usage of it is:

```
$('elementId')
```

Valid code can looks like:

```
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

function todayTxt() {
   var today = new Date();
   return today.getMonth() + 1 + "-" + today.getDate() + "-" + today.getFullYear();
}

var initForm = function() {
    $('qty1').focus();
}

window.onload = function() {
    initForm();
    todayTxt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're not *calling* the function.

```
$(something);
```

is retrieving `something`, but not calling it as a function.

Why are you using `$(something)` instead of calling `initform();` as a regular function?

Answer (score 0):

Following the call chain from the entry-point (`window.onload`), you are only actually calling 2 functions:

1. Your anonymous function for `onload`.
2. The `$` function.

You have defined `$` as `document.getElementById(id)`.  When you call `$`, you are passing **references** to the `initForm` and `todayTxt` function into `$` as the `id` parameter.

In otherwords, when you call

```
$(initForm)
```

when entering $, we are calling

```
document.getElementById(initForm);
```

Since neither function has anything to do with `$`, you probably are looking for:

```
window.onload = function () {
    initForm();
    todayTxt();
}
```